# App Not Receiving Property from SBT Command

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to obtain a property passed from execution and use it, but when I try to pass the property from IntelliJ as a VM parameter, it works. However, when I try to pass it using sbt, my property is not picked up.

**Code to read property**

```
val file = System.getProperty("config.resource", "application.conf")
println(file)
```

**Using IntelliJ run configuration**

```
-Dconfig.resource=application.ci.conf
```

results in

```
application.ci.conf
```

**Using SBT CLI**

```
sbt -Dconfig.resource=application.ci.conf test
```

results in

```
application.conf
```

Why is the first working and not the second?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line to your build.sbt

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=application.ci.conf"
```

or if you want to add it at the command line

```
sbt 'set javaOptions += "-Dconfig.resource=application.ci.conf"' test
```